# Member custom profile data not outputting correctly

Tags: members, custom-fields, member-details

I've created a custom member field called "member_code", I'm trying to output this code but it seems to only ever output the code from the first member in the system, even when I use the member_id="3" parameter. My code is as follows:

```
{exp:member:custom_profile_data}{member_code}{/exp:member:custom_profile_data}
```

No matter which user I login as it's always outputting the first users details, any ideas? I'm running expressionengine 2.6.1

Comment: Seems to only output the incorrect value when it's inside a {exp:channel:entries} tag, if it's outside it'll work…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have to wrap {exp:member:custom_profile_data} around {exp:channel:entries} instead of placing it inside!

Answer (score 2):

You can use put the code for fetching member data within embedded template and can pass member id as embed variable like:

```
{embed="temp_grp/temp_name" member_id="{member_id}"}
```

Within the template "temp_grp/temp_name" put the tag of custom profile data:

like:

```
{exp:member:custom_profile_data member_id="{embed:member_id}"}{member_code}{/exp:member:custom_profile_data}
```

Comment: Thanks this works but I found an alternative method too!